# Swift Merge audio and video files into one video

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation

I wrote a program in Swift.I want to merge a video with an audio file, but got this error.

> "failed Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11838 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo=0x17da4230 {NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The operation is not supported for this media.}"

**code**

```
func mergeAudio(audioURL: NSURL, moviePathUrl: NSURL, savePathUrl: NSURL) {
    var composition = AVMutableComposition()
    let trackVideo:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
    let trackAudio:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
    let option = NSDictionary(object: true, forKey: "AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey")
    let sourceAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: moviePathUrl, options: option as [NSObject : AnyObject])
    let audioAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: audioURL, options: option as [NSObject : AnyObject])

    let tracks = sourceAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    let audios = audioAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)

    if tracks.count > 0 {
        let assetTrack:AVAssetTrack = tracks[0] as! AVAssetTrack
        let assetTrackAudio:AVAssetTrack = audios[0] as! AVAssetTrack

        let audioDuration:CMTime = assetTrackAudio.timeRange.duration
        let audioSeconds:Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(assetTrackAudio.timeRange.duration)

        trackVideo.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,audioDuration), ofTrack: assetTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero, error: nil)
        trackAudio.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,audioDuration), ofTrack: assetTrackAudio, atTime: kCMTimeZero, error: nil)
    }

    var assetExport: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)
    assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    assetExport.outputURL = savePathUrl
    self.tmpMovieURL = savePathUrl
    assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    assetExport.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler { () -> Void in
        switch assetExport.status {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed:
            let assetsLib = ALAssetsLibrary()
            assetsLib.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(savePathUrl, completionBlock: nil)
            println("success")
        case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
            println("failed \(assetExport.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
            println("cancelled \(assetExport.error)")
        default:
            println("complete")
        }
    }

}
```

In my idea media type like mpeg4 is wrong.
Where is the problem? What am i missing?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Not yet.Still searching solution.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 32):

**Improved** code (of Govind's answer) **with** some additional **features**:

1. **Merge audio of the video + external audio** (the initial answer was dropping the sound of the video)
2. **Flip video horizontally** if needed (I personally use it when user captures using frontal camera, btw instagram flips it too)
3. Apply `preferredTransform` correctly which **solves the issue** when video was saved rotated (video is external: captured by other device/generated by other app)
4. **Removed** some **unused code** with VideoComposition.
5. Added a **completion handler** to the method so that it can be called from a different class.
6. Update to **Swift 4**.

Step 1.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
import AssetsLibrary
```

Step 2.

```
/// Merges video and sound while keeping sound of the video too
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - videoUrl: URL to video file
///   - audioUrl: URL to audio file
///   - shouldFlipHorizontally: pass True if video was recorded using frontal camera otherwise pass False
///   - completion: completion of saving: error or url with final video
func mergeVideoAndAudio(videoUrl: URL,
                        audioUrl: URL,
                        shouldFlipHorizontally: Bool = false,
                        completion: @escaping (_ error: Error?, _ url: URL?) -> Void) {

    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    var mutableCompositionVideoTrack = [AVMutableCompositionTrack]()
    var mutableCompositionAudioTrack = [AVMutableCompositionTrack]()
    var mutableCompositionAudioOfVideoTrack = [AVMutableCompositionTrack]()

    //start merge

    let aVideoAsset = AVAsset(url: videoUrl)
    let aAudioAsset = AVAsset(url: audioUrl)

    let compositionAddVideo = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video,
                                                             preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!

    let compositionAddAudio = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio,
                                                             preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!

    let compositionAddAudioOfVideo = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio,
                                                                    preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)!

    let aVideoAssetTrack: AVAssetTrack = aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]
    let aAudioOfVideoAssetTrack: AVAssetTrack? = aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).first
    let aAudioAssetTrack: AVAssetTrack = aAudioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)[0]

    // Default must have tranformation
    compositionAddVideo.preferredTransform = aVideoAssetTrack.preferredTransform

    if shouldFlipHorizontally {
        // Flip video horizontally
        var frontalTransform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
        frontalTransform = frontalTransform.translatedBy(x: -aVideoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width, y: 0.0)
        frontalTransform = frontalTransform.translatedBy(x: 0.0, y: -aVideoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width)
        compositionAddVideo.preferredTransform = frontalTransform
    }

    mutableCompositionVideoTrack.append(compositionAddVideo)
    mutableCompositionAudioTrack.append(compositionAddAudio)
    mutableCompositionAudioOfVideoTrack.append(compositionAddAudioOfVideo)

    do {
        try mutableCompositionVideoTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero,
                                                                            duration: aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration),
                                                            of: aVideoAssetTrack,
                                                            at: CMTime.zero)

        //In my case my audio file is longer then video file so i took videoAsset duration
        //instead of audioAsset duration
        try mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero,
                                                                            duration: aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration),
                                                            of: aAudioAssetTrack,
                                                            at: CMTime.zero)

        // adding audio (of the video if exists) asset to the final composition
        if let aAudioOfVideoAssetTrack = aAudioOfVideoAssetTrack {
            try mutableCompositionAudioOfVideoTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero,
                                                                                       duration: aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration),
                                                                       of: aAudioOfVideoAssetTrack,
                                                                       at: CMTime.zero)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    // Exporting
    let savePathUrl: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/newVideo.mp4")
    do { // delete old video
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: savePathUrl)
    } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }

    let assetExport: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
    assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    assetExport.outputURL = savePathUrl
    assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

    assetExport.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in
        switch assetExport.status {
        case AVAssetExportSession.Status.completed:
            print("success")
            completion(nil, savePathUrl)
        case AVAssetExportSession.Status.failed:
            print("failed \(assetExport.error?.localizedDescription ?? "error nil")")
            completion(assetExport.error, nil)
        case AVAssetExportSession.Status.cancelled:
            print("cancelled \(assetExport.error?.localizedDescription ?? "error nil")")
            completion(assetExport.error, nil)
        default:
            print("complete")
            completion(assetExport.error, nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Again thanks to @Govind's answer! It helped me a lot!

Hope this update helps someone too:)

Comment: What changes should I make if I want the original audio from the video to be entirely replaced with the external audio file. ?

Comment: @omarojo I'm not sure If it's convenient to provide an answer in comments for such a big question. Feel free to create a new question and I'll reply there. Send me a link in comments once you created it. I'll try to help.

Comment: I actually figured it out I just commented the lines in your code where you were including the video’s original audio.

Comment: @omarojo that's great! glad you figured it out:) don't forget to upvote the answer so other people can notice it's helpfulness.

Comment: this works perfectly! thanks for the updated function + completion handler

Comment: How to stop downloading process?

Comment: @Alfi which downloading process are you referring to? In the steps described, there is no downloading process.

Comment: @Tung Fam the video is downloading from a web url anyway! how can stop it if user wanted to stop the whole operation?

Comment: @Alfi I don't think it's related to this question/answer. Moreover I don't know how you download the video. In my case I take it from the folder on the phone. But a general advice is that try to google for a specific problem that you have since this qa is not related to your problem.

Comment: Super Helpful! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15):

> > > In Above question same error I found due to wrong savePathUrl, destination URL should be like below code including new video name.

*I was looking for the code to **Merge audio and video files into one video** but couldn't find anywhere so after spending hours while reading apple docs I wrote this code*.

> NOTE : This is tested and **100% working code** for me.

Stap : 1
Import this modules in your viewController.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
import AssetsLibrary
```

step 2:
Add this function in your code

```
func mergeFilesWithUrl(videoUrl:NSURL, audioUrl:NSURL)
{
    let mixComposition : AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    var mutableCompositionVideoTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
    var mutableCompositionAudioTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
    let totalVideoCompositionInstruction : AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()


    //start merge

    let aVideoAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(URL: videoUrl)
    let aAudioAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(URL: audioUrl)

    mutableCompositionVideoTrack.append(mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    mutableCompositionAudioTrack.append( mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

    let aVideoAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aVideoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
    let aAudioAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aAudioAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]



    do{
        try mutableCompositionVideoTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), ofTrack: aVideoAssetTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)

        //In my case my audio file is longer then video file so i took videoAsset duration
        //instead of audioAsset duration

        try mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), ofTrack: aAudioAssetTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)

        //Use this instead above line if your audiofile and video file's playing durations are same

        //            try mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), ofTrack: aAudioAssetTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)

    }catch{

    }

    totalVideoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration )

    let mutableVideoComposition : AVMutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)

    mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(1280,720)

    //        playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: mixComposition)
    //        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)
    //
    //
    //        AVPlayerVC.player = player



    //find your video on this URl
    let savePathUrl : NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/newVideo.mp4")

    let assetExport: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
    assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    assetExport.outputURL = savePathUrl
    assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

    assetExport.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler { () -> Void in
        switch assetExport.status {

        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed:

            //Uncomment this if u want to store your video in asset

            //let assetsLib = ALAssetsLibrary()
            //assetsLib.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(savePathUrl, completionBlock: nil)

            print("success")
        case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed:
            print("failed \(assetExport.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Cancelled:
            print("cancelled \(assetExport.error)")
        default:
            print("complete")
        }
    }


}
```

Step 3:
Call function where u want like this

```
let videoUrl : NSURL =  NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SampleVideo", ofType: "mp4")!)
let audioUrl : NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SampleAudio", ofType: "mp3")!)

mergeFilesWithUrl(videoUrl, audioUrl: audioUrl)
```

hope this will help you and will save your time.

Comment: it is not working if the a recorder sound was is format AVFileTypeAppleM4A, any suggestions?

Comment: Video's original audio removed if I am adding my custom audio. I want original video's sound also and want to append my custom sound. can you help me?

Comment: Sorry friend, all I have is above code and don't have time to explore more.

Comment: @parth Hey dude, I found a solution. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45313680/composing-video-and-audio-videos-audio-is-gone/45327843#45327843

Comment: The three lines that pertain to 'mutableVideoComposition' are useless and should be deleted

Comment: @DumitruRogojinaru did you find a solution about M4A format, man?

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4.2 / 5**

```
func mergeVideoWithAudio(videoUrl: URL, audioUrl: URL, success: @escaping ((URL) -> Void), failure: @escaping ((Error?) -> Void)) {


    let mixComposition: AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    var mutableCompositionVideoTrack: [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
    var mutableCompositionAudioTrack: [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
    let totalVideoCompositionInstruction : AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

    let aVideoAsset: AVAsset = AVAsset(url: videoUrl)
    let aAudioAsset: AVAsset = AVAsset(url: audioUrl)

    if let videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid), let audioTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) {
        mutableCompositionVideoTrack.append(videoTrack)
        mutableCompositionAudioTrack.append(audioTrack)

    if let aVideoAssetTrack: AVAssetTrack = aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first, let aAudioAssetTrack: AVAssetTrack = aAudioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first {
        do {
            try mutableCompositionVideoTrack.first?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aVideoAssetTrack, at: CMTime.zero)
            try mutableCompositionAudioTrack.first?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aAudioAssetTrack, at: CMTime.zero)
               videoTrack.preferredTransform = aVideoAssetTrack.preferredTransform 

        } catch{
            print(error)
        }


       totalVideoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero,duration: aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration)
    }
    }

    let mutableVideoComposition: AVMutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 480, height: 640)

    if let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first {
        let outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath).appendingPathComponent("\("fileName").m4v")

        do {
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: outputURL.path) {

                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputURL)
            }
        } catch { }

        if let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) {
            exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
            exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
            exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

            /// try to export the file and handle the status cases
            exportSession.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
                switch exportSession.status {
                case .failed:
                    if let _error = exportSession.error {
                        failure(_error)
                    }

                case .cancelled:
                    if let _error = exportSession.error {
                        failure(_error)
                    }

                default:
                    print("finished")
                    success(outputURL)
                }
            })
        } else {
            failure(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i merge two wav file?

Answer (score 3):

Version Swift3 with URL and new syntax.

```
func mergeFilesWithUrl(videoUrl:URL, audioUrl:URL)
{
    let mixComposition : AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    var mutableCompositionVideoTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
    var mutableCompositionAudioTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
    let totalVideoCompositionInstruction : AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()


    //start merge

    let aVideoAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(url: videoUrl)
    let aAudioAsset : AVAsset = AVAsset(url: audioUrl)

    mutableCompositionVideoTrack.append(mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    mutableCompositionAudioTrack.append( mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

    let aVideoAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
    let aAudioAssetTrack : AVAssetTrack = aAudioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)[0]



    do{
        try mutableCompositionVideoTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aVideoAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)

        //In my case my audio file is longer then video file so i took videoAsset duration
        //instead of audioAsset duration

        try mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aAudioAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)

        //Use this instead above line if your audiofile and video file's playing durations are same

        //            try mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), ofTrack: aAudioAssetTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)

    }catch{

    }

    totalVideoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration )

    let mutableVideoComposition : AVMutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)

    mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 1280, height: 720)
    //        playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: mixComposition)
    //        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)
    //
    //
    //        AVPlayerVC.player = player

    //find your video on this URl
    let savePathUrl : URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/newVideo.mp4")

    let assetExport: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
    assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    assetExport.outputURL = savePathUrl
    assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

    assetExport.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in
        switch assetExport.status {

        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed:

            //Uncomment this if u want to store your video in asset

            //let assetsLib = ALAssetsLibrary()
            //assetsLib.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(savePathUrl, completionBlock: nil)

            print("success")
        case  AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
            print("failed \(assetExport.error)")
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
            print("cancelled \(assetExport.error)")
        default:
            print("complete")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any way merging two wav file i am getting crash at assetExport?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: { [weak self] in}

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 version (Also repeats audio if video is larger than audio) : Just pass audio and video URLs. I have tried this with local video and remote audio url.

```
func mergeVideoWithAudio(videoUrl: URL,
                                audioUrl: URL,
                                success: @escaping ((URL) -> Void),
                                failure: @escaping ((Error?) -> Void)) {

       let mixComposition: AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
       var mutableCompositionVideoTrack: [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
       var mutableCompositionAudioTrack: [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
       let totalVideoCompositionInstruction: AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

       let aVideoAsset: AVAsset = AVAsset(url: videoUrl)
       let aAudioAsset: AVAsset = AVAsset(url: audioUrl)

       if let videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid), let audioTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) {
           mutableCompositionVideoTrack.append( videoTrack )
           mutableCompositionAudioTrack.append( audioTrack )

           if let aVideoAssetTrack: AVAssetTrack = aVideoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first, let aAudioAssetTrack: AVAssetTrack = aAudioAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first {
               do {
                   try mutableCompositionVideoTrack.first?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aVideoAssetTrack, at: CMTime.zero)

                   let videoDuration = aVideoAsset.duration
                   if CMTimeCompare(videoDuration, aAudioAsset.duration) == -1 {
                       try mutableCompositionAudioTrack.first?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aAudioAssetTrack, at: CMTime.zero)
                   } else if CMTimeCompare(videoDuration, aAudioAsset.duration) == 1 {
                       var currentTime = CMTime.zero
                       while true {
                           var audioDuration = aAudioAsset.duration
                           let totalDuration = CMTimeAdd(currentTime, audioDuration)
                           if CMTimeCompare(totalDuration, videoDuration) == 1 {
                               audioDuration = CMTimeSubtract(totalDuration, videoDuration)
                           }
                           try mutableCompositionAudioTrack.first?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: aAudioAssetTrack, at: currentTime)

                           currentTime = CMTimeAdd(currentTime, audioDuration)
                           if CMTimeCompare(currentTime, videoDuration) == 1 || CMTimeCompare(currentTime, videoDuration) == 0 {
                               break
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   videoTrack.preferredTransform = aVideoAssetTrack.preferredTransform

               } catch {
                   print(error)
               }

               totalVideoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: aVideoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration)
           }
       }

       let mutableVideoComposition: AVMutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
       mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
       mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: 480, height: 640)

       if let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first {
           let outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath).appendingPathComponent("\("fileName").m4v")

           do {
               if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: outputURL.path) {

                   try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: outputURL)
               }
           } catch { }

           if let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) {
               exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
               exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
               exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

               // try to export the file and handle the status cases
               exportSession.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
                   switch exportSession.status {
                   case .failed:
                       if let error = exportSession.error {
                           failure(error)
                       }

                   case .cancelled:
                       if let error = exportSession.error {
                           failure(error)
                       }

                   default:
                       print("finished")
                       success(outputURL)
                   }
               })
           } else {
               failure(nil)
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated for Swift Concurrency (Swift 5.7)

Some errors to throw:

```
enum VideoAudioMergeError: Error {
    case compositionAddVideoFailed, compositionAddAudioFailed, compositionAddAudioOfVideoFailed, unknownError
}
```

And the method:

```
/// Merges video and sound while keeping sound of the video too
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - videoUrl: URL to video file
///   - audioUrl: URL to audio file
///   - shouldFlipHorizontally: pass True if video was recorded using frontal camera otherwise pass False
func mergeVideoAndAudio(videoUrl: URL,
                        audioUrl: URL,
                        shouldFlipHorizontally: Bool = false) async throws -> URL {

    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    var mutableCompositionVideoTrack = [AVMutableCompositionTrack]()
    var mutableCompositionAudioTrack = [AVMutableCompositionTrack]()
    var mutableCompositionAudioOfVideoTrack = [AVMutableCompositionTrack]()

    //start merge

    let aVideoAsset = AVAsset(url: videoUrl)
    let aAudioAsset = AVAsset(url: audioUrl)

    guard let compositionAddVideo = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video,
                                                                   preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) else {
        throw VideoAudioMergeError.compositionAddVideoFailed
    }

    guard let compositionAddAudio = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio,
                                                                   preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) else {
        throw VideoAudioMergeError.compositionAddAudioFailed
    }

    guard let compositionAddAudioOfVideo = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio,
                                                                          preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid) else {
        throw VideoAudioMergeError.compositionAddAudioOfVideoFailed
    }

    do {
        let aVideoAssetTrack: AVAssetTrack = try await aVideoAsset.loadTracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]
        let aAudioOfVideoAssetTrack: AVAssetTrack? = try await  aVideoAsset.loadTracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio).first
        let aAudioAssetTrack: AVAssetTrack = try await aAudioAsset.loadTracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)[0]

        // Default must have transformation
        compositionAddVideo.preferredTransform = try await aVideoAssetTrack.load(.preferredTransform)

        if shouldFlipHorizontally {
            // Flip video horizontally
            var frontalTransform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1.0, y: 1.0)
            let naturalSize = try await aVideoAssetTrack.load(.naturalSize)
            frontalTransform = frontalTransform.translatedBy(x: -naturalSize.width, y: 0.0)
            frontalTransform = frontalTransform.translatedBy(x: 0.0, y: -naturalSize.width)
            compositionAddVideo.preferredTransform = frontalTransform
        }

        mutableCompositionVideoTrack.append(compositionAddVideo)
        mutableCompositionAudioTrack.append(compositionAddAudio)
        mutableCompositionAudioOfVideoTrack.append(compositionAddAudioOfVideo)
        
        let videoTimeRange = try await aVideoAssetTrack.load(.timeRange)

        try mutableCompositionVideoTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero,
                                                                            duration: videoTimeRange.duration),
                                                            of: aVideoAssetTrack,
                                                            at: CMTime.zero)

        //In my case my audio file is longer then video file so i took videoAsset duration
        //instead of audioAsset duration
        try mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero,
                                                                            duration: videoTimeRange.duration),
                                                            of: aAudioAssetTrack,
                                                            at: CMTime.zero)

        // adding audio (of the video if exists) asset to the final composition
        if let aAudioOfVideoAssetTrack = aAudioOfVideoAssetTrack {
            try mutableCompositionAudioOfVideoTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero,
                                                                                       duration: videoTimeRange.duration),
                                                                       of: aAudioOfVideoAssetTrack,
                                                                       at: CMTime.zero)
        }
    } catch {
        throw error
    }

    // Exporting
    let savePathUrl: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/newVideo.mp4")
    do { // delete old video
        try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: savePathUrl)
    } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }

    let assetExport: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
    assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    assetExport.outputURL = savePathUrl
    assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

    await assetExport.export()
    
    if assetExport.status == .completed {
        return savePathUrl
    }
    
    if let error = assetExport.error {
        throw error
    } else {
        throw VideoAudioMergeError.unknownError
    }
}
```